# not able to run cucumber testrunner

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import testng.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:src/test/java/qspromo/automation/features"},
        glue = {"stepdefination"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/html"}
        )

public class TestRunner {
}
```

Receiving :

No features found at [classpath:qspromo/automation/testrunner]

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

Comment: Your error and code don't match up. You may want to investigate that.

Answer (score 1):

Mine looks like this and it works:

```
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = "pretty",
    monochrome = true,
    tags = "not @wip",
    features = "src/test/resources/Features",
    glue = {"test.java.StepDefinitions"},
    junit = "--step-notifications"
    )
```